# Mathf.Atan2 return incorrect result

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, trigonometry

Sometimes when i move mouse (rotate camera around character), my character do rotation.
But i do not have any character rotation by mouse.
This is my rotation code, that depend only on keyboard input (I took this code from standard unity sample):

```
private void ConvertMoveInput()
{
    Vector3 localMove = transform.InverseTransformDirection(_moveInput);
    _turnAmount = Mathf.Atan2(localMove.x, localMove.z);
    _forwardAmount = localMove.z;
}
```

I figure out that sometimes when i move mouse Mathf.Atan2 return the number PI, even if two arguments are still equals to zero. How does this happens?

[image: Breakpoint]

My demo project [here](http://stasclick.zz.mu/Test1.html).

Comment: `Atan2(0,0)` is invalid because you are dividing by zero (and there would be no mathematical solution for this case). Are there any other examples with wrong values?

Comment: @Jibbow that's mean that it is a bug in Unity Sample. Maybe i have to check if `localMove.x + localMove.z < 0.01f` and if it true, then return zero?

Comment: @StasBZ No and no. It's not a bug, it's just a bias. The real problem is that when you reach the `[0; 0]` coordinate, there's no preferred angle to choose. See my answer for some more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember, `atan2(x, z)` returns the angle between the z-axis and the vector **(x, z)**:

[image: Graph showing the vector (x, z), atan2(x, z), and atan2(z, x)]

But with `atan2(0, 0)`, you're trying to find the angle between a point and either the z- or x-axis, which is meaningless:

[image]

Even though `atan2(0, 0)` is meaningless, most programming language math libraries have `atan2(x, y)` to return a value instead of an error code if `x` and `y` are valid numbers, and in the special case of `atan2(0, 0)`, that return value is pi. [The implementation of `atan2()` in the C++ standard library does this,](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2) and I think a lot of languages, including Unity's implementation of C#, followed suit.

This means that you need to check for the special case where `x` and `z` are both 0. Something like:

```
if ((localMove.x != 0) && (localMove.z != 0)) {
  _turnAmount = Mathf.Atan2(localMove.x, localMove.z);
}
else {
  _turnAmount = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `tan` function is periodic with a period of `π`. So calling `tan` on `0` and on `π` produces the same value (namely, zero).

That's one of the reasons you can't simply use `atan` to get back the original angle - you're losing a lot of the original information, and the angle you'll get will only ever be between `-π/2` and `+π/2`.

`Atan2` in Unity is designed to work around this - it takes the `x` and `y` coordinates, instead of their division (which is how you'd use `atan`). It can then figure out the correct *quadrant* for the angle - offset it appropriately. Just as importantly, it handles the case when the `y` coordinate is zero - which would normally result in a division-by-zero error. For example, `[1; 0]` might return 0°, `[0; 1]` 270° (note - I'm not sure about the exact numbers; it depends on where the "reference" is, and I haven't used this in Unity3D. The key point is the principle, not the exact values).

**However**, this can only work if at least one of the coordinates is *not* zero - the coordinate `[0; 0]` *doesn't* have any meaningful angle with respect to `[0; 0]`. All the angles are equally valid (or neither of them, depending on your viewpoint). Unity simply chooses `π`, out of all the possible options - for whatever reason. It really is as good a value as any other. The only real alternative would be to throw an exception and crash your game - which usually wouldn't be preferred to tiny glitches like this :)

Comment: As I'm sure you know many languages' runtime libraries have `atan2()` functions for precisely this reason. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: @OllieJones Yes. Do I indicate otherwise? In fact, I'm *describing* the `Atan2` function (in principle, if not in implementation - that tends to vary a bit).

Comment: You used the phrase "Atan2 in Unity..." that's why I chimed in.

Comment: The definition of atan2(0,0) is stated by many specs as "indeterminate." I prefer the ancient and honorable IBM wording: "unpredictable." So a result of π is a pretty good result.

Comment: @OllieJones Yeah, but "indeterminate" kind of sucks for anything. Either you're working with exact computations and you want it to give you an error (so you'll have to handle the edge case explicitly), or you don't care about tiny things like this, so any answer is as good as any other, as long as it's consistent. Look where "undefined" in C/C++ got us :D In a 3D engine, `π` really is as good as any other value - a scenario like this would usually appear when you're skimming over some object, and at just one tiny point, you're exactly at `[0; 0]` - your camera is going to turn around the point